# string functions don't work on {{ run_id }} in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG containing;

```
run_id = "{{ run_id }}"
session_id = str(run_id).replace(":","-").replace("+","-")
```

and when I run the dag and just print the session_id i get:

```
manual__2021-05-07T08:28:31.651045+00:00
```

so obviously replace functions don't work.

When I execute code like this:

```
run_id = "manual__2021-05-07T08:28:31.651045+00:00"
session_id = str(run_id).replace(":","-").replace("+","-")
```

it works and returns

```
manual__2021-05-07T08-28-31.651045-00-00
```

Why it doesn't work with `{{ run_id }}` ?
I'm stuck. Any hint?

Airflow 2.0

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

The jinja template is running when the task is run, not when the script is run. You need to add `user_defined_macros` to your DAG. It will be something like this:

```
def run_id_format(run_id):
   return str(run_id).replace(":","-").replace("+","-")

user_defined_macros={
   "run_id_format":run_id_format,
}
dag=DAG(
   dag_id="test",
   user_defined_macros=user_defined_macros
)

task=BashOperator(
   task_id="task_test",
   bash_command="echo {{ user_defined_macros(run_id) }}",
   dag=dag
)

task
```

Or, you can use `provide_context` if you use `PythonOperator`.